# A surface lies on a sphere or a plane if every normal section curve of it is a geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $S$ is a regular surface such that each normal section curve of it is a geodesic. I want to show that $S$ is either a part of a sphere or a part of a plane.

Edited:

My progress:

If I just prove that $S$ is all-umbilic, then the rest will be easy. Let $\sigma:U\to V$ be a surface patch for $V\subset S$ and $\mathbf n$ be the normal vector of $S$.

If $k$ is the principal curvature for $S$, then we have:

$d\mathbf n(\sigma_u)=-\mathbf n_u=k\sigma_u$

$d\mathbf n(\sigma_v)=-\mathbf n_v=k\sigma_v$

Differentiating yields:

$-\mathbf n_{uv}=k_v\sigma_u+k\sigma_{uv}$

$-\mathbf n_{vu}=k_u\sigma_v+k\sigma_{vu}$

And therefore:

$k_v\sigma_u - k_u\sigma_v=0$

yielding $k_v,k_u=0$ as $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_v$ are linearly independent. So $k$ is constant everywhere. Back to the equations $-\mathbf n_u=k\sigma_u$ and $-\mathbf n_v=k\sigma_v$, we get $\mathbf n=k\sigma+\vec{c}$ for a constant vector $\vec c$.

Now we consider two cases:

If $k=0$ everywhere then $V\subset S$ is a part of a plane

If $k\neq 0$ then taking norm from the sides of $\frac{1}{k}\mathbf n=\sigma+\frac{1}{k}\vec{c}$ implies $\|\sigma - (-\frac{1}{k}\vec{c})\|=\frac{1}{|k|}$, meaning that $V\subset S$ is a part of a sphere.

My only question is how we can prove that $S$ is all-umbilic considering the fact that all normal sections are geodesics.

I’m currently studying Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces by Kristopher Tapp and couldn’t find anything about planar geodesics.

Comment: You are right that there are two steps. First, you must show that a (connected) all-umbilic surface is a subset of a plane or sphere. Second, you must use the geodesic fact. How do you relate the Frenet frame to the Darboux frame along a planar geodesic? Let’s see some serious efforts.

Comment: If I only prove that every point of $S$ is umbilical, then the rest is easy. If $\sigma$ is a surface patch for $V\subset S$ and $\mathbf n$ is a unit normal vector for it, then differentiating the relations $d\mathbf n(\sigma_u)=-\mathbf n_u=k\sigma_u$ and $d\mathbf n(\sigma_v)=-\mathbf n_v=k\sigma_v$ where $k$ is the principal curvature for $S$ implies that $k$ is constant and that $\mathbf n=-k\sigma+\vec c$ where $\vec c$ is a constant vector. The result immediately follows (we only have to consider the cases $k=0$ or $k\neq 0$). But how can I show that $S$ is all-umbilic?

Comment: You should edit your post with your efforts/progress, rather than filling up all the comments. OK, so you knew how to do that part. Now did you answer the question I asked in my first comment? If you have a planar geodesic, how are its principal normal and binormal related to the surface normal? Work with that and edit the post.

Comment: You continue to ignore my explicit hints for the remaining question. Why not try?